# Rootkits, Bootkits detection and protection and Firmware alteration

Tags: attacks, mobile

I was hacked in an extremely intrusive manner in late 2013. Ever since then, not a day has passed where I don't think about this. A lot. My question has to do with the likelihood of the attackers having altered my BIOS so they would have persistent access to my information, even if I wiped the hard drive(s) and changed operating systems, which I did. (I've been learning about Linux ever since) I believe this is referred to as either a rootkit or a bootkit. Along those same lines, how difficult would it be to alter the firmware on my Android(s) in order to guard against Factory Data Resets? Finally, how can I detect some of these attacks having been performed on me?

Thanks

Comment: You say `BIOS` but also mention `mobile` and `android`. Are you talking about Windows or Android? Android's don't have BIOS. They store the ROM directly in the PROM and boot from there. See [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635820/what-is-bios-in-android).

Comment: I'm talking about both. My laptop that was running Windows 8.1, my tablet running Jelly Bean and my Phone running Android 2.3 were all compromised. I suppose I should clarify that when bringing up firmware, I was wondering if an attacker could alter it in any way so as to keep their victim persistently compromised. Given the manner in which I was attacked, I believe it would be prudent to assume that my attackers had been planning this for a long time. I did take quite a few mental notes on my attackers but am unsure if it would be appropriate to detail them here, in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

If attackers had administrator/system/root level privileges on your computer, they have a lot of possibilities to permanently backdoor your computer. Not many attackers can do this kind of persistence, but it is possible.

- MBR bootkit - can be cleaned via formatting from live cd
- BIOS/UEFI malware - see [Computrace rootkit](https://securelist.com/analysis/publications/58278/absolute-computrace-revisited/)
- HDD firmware - [GrayFish malware](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/02/how-omnipotent-hackers-tied-to-the-nsa-hid-for-14-years-and-were-found-at-last/1/)
- GPU/Ethernet/other firmware modification
- [Hardware implants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSA_ANT_catalog)

The best solution is to box all of your devices which has more than 0% chance of infection (and label the box with something like "infected, don't use"), and buy a new computer and a new phone - but don't order it to your home, go and buy one in a random local store. And don't trust any of your old data from old backups. Based on your paranoid level, not even image, music, video files can be trusted - but it is 99% they are safe. MS Office documents can be a risk more likely.

I believe the same attacks are more or less possible on Android devices, but there are no known cases of these - at least I know of. I think the easiest backdoor would be to replace the bootloader.

Detecting such intrusive rootkits are hard. There is no simple way to check for rootkits. The easiest way to do this is to disable the services on your computer which communicate with the internet until nothing should communicate, and run tcpdump on your router for days. After that, analyse the traffic and look for unknown IPs/domains. Meanwhile, check for side channel leaks like WiFi or Bluetooth. Most rootkits can be found via this method. Creating fake activity (e.g. typing in a text editor, generating new fake PGP keys) might help trigger the bad traffic.
When it comes to rootkit detection on Windows, my personal experience is that [GMER](http://www.gmer.net/) can find most rootkits - but not all.